# Audio Queue Services - write audio to file (iOS)

Tags: ios, core-audio, audio-recording

Please give some sample of code how to write recorded audio data to file (e.g. in tmp folder with "audio.m4a" file name) from this callback method:

```
static void MyAudioQueueInputCallback(void *inUserData, 
                                      AudioQueueRef inQueue,
                                      AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer,
                                      const AudioTimeStamp *inStartTime,
                                      UInt32 inNumPackets,
                                      const AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDesc) 
{
        MyRecorder *recorder = (MyRecorder *)inUserData;

        // what to do here ??

}
```

Recorder struct:

```
typedef struct MyRecorder {
    AudioFileID recordFile;
    UInt64 recordPacket;
    Boolean running;
    AudioQueueRef queue;
    BOOL mute;
}MyRecorder;

- (void)stopRecording
{
   //Save logic

   // what to do here ??
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802